Spacy "Can't load model from config file: no [nlp] section"
i tried running the code and implemented various methods but im keep facing this error
ValueError: [E985] Can't load model from config file: no [nlp] section found. {'nltk': {'stopwords': 'stopwords'}, 'spacy': {'model': 'en_core_web_sm'}}
i have given the required code below that contains the major part that constitutes the error.
import streamlit as st
import nltk
import spacy
nltk.download('stopwords')
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

import pandas as pd
import base64, random
import time, datetime
from pyresparser import ResumeParser
from pdfminer3.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox
from pdfminer3.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer3.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer3.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer3.converter import TextConverter
import io, random
from streamlit_tags import st_tags
from PIL import Image
import pymysql
from Courses import ds_course, web_course, android_course, ios_course, uiux_course, resume_videos, interview_videos
import pafy
import plotly.express as px

def pdf_reader(file):
    try:
        resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
        fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
        converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle, laparams=LAParams())
        page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)
        with open(file, 'rb') as fh:
            for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh, caching=True, check_extractable=True):
                page_interpreter.process_page(page)
        text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()
    except Exception as e:
        st.error(f"An error occurred while reading the PDF: {e}")
        text = ""
    finally:
        converter.close()
        fake_file_handle.close()
    return text


def show_pdf(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        base64_pdf = base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode('utf-8')
    # pdf_display = f'<embed src="data:application/pdf;base64,{base64_pdf}" width="700" height="1000" type="application/pdf">'
    pdf_display = F'<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,{base64_pdf}" width="700" height="1000" type="application/pdf"></iframe>'
    st.markdown(pdf_display, unsafe_allow_html=True)




st.set_page_config(
    page_title="Resume Analyzer",
    page_icon='./Logo/resumeAnalyserLogo.png',
)


def run():
    st.title("Smart Resume Analyser")
    st.sidebar.markdown("# Choose User")
    activities = ["Normal User", "Admin"]
    choice = st.sidebar.selectbox("Choose among the given options:", activities)
    # link = '[©Developed by Spidy20](http://github.com/spidy20)'
    # st.sidebar.markdown(link, unsafe_allow_html=True)
    img = Image.open('./Logo/resumeAnalyserLogo.png')
    
    if choice == 'Normal User':
        # st.markdown('''<h4 style='text-align: left; color: #d73b5c;'>* Upload your resume, and get smart recommendation based on it."</h4>''',
        #             unsafe_allow_html=True)
        pdf_file = st.file_uploader("Choose your Resume", type=["pdf"])
        if pdf_file is not None:
            # with st.spinner('Uploading your Resume....'):
            #     time.sleep(4)
            save_image_path = './Uploaded_Resumes/' + pdf_file.name
            with open(save_image_path, "wb") as f:
                f.write(pdf_file.getbuffer())
            show_pdf(save_image_path)
            resume_data = ResumeParser(save_image_path).get_extracted_data()
            if resume_data:
                ## Get the whole resume data
                resume_text = pdf_reader(save_image_path)

                st.header("**Resume Analysis**")
                st.success("Hello " + resume_data['name'])
                st.subheader("**Your Basic info**")
                try:
                    st.text('Name: ' + resume_data['name'])
                    st.text('Email: ' + resume_data['email'])
                    st.text('Contact: ' + resume_data['mobile_number'])
                    st.text('Resume pages: ' + str(resume_data['no_of_pages']))
                except:
                    pass
                cand_level = ''
                if resume_data['no_of_pages'] == 1:
                    cand_level = "Fresher"
                    st.markdown('''<h4 style='text-align: left; color: #d73b5c;'>You are looking Fresher.</h4>''',
                                unsafe_allow_html=True)
                elif resume_data['no_of_pages'] == 2:
                    cand_level = "Intermediate"
                    st.markdown('''<h4 style='text-align: left; color: #1ed760;'>You are at intermediate level!</h4>''',
                                unsafe_allow_html=True)
                elif resume_data['no_of_pages'] >= 3:
                    

              


run()

I tried upgrading and downgrading the spacy and other dependencies versions so that they could match.
I tried setting up the config.cfg manually
I tried making some changes in resume_parser.py changing this line custom_nlp = spacy.load(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) to custom_nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

I've edited your question title to be more descriptive of the specific problem. Please try to do this yourself in the future.

Thanks a lot, its my first time using stack overflow. I'll keep that in mind for future questions

By the way, are you able to reproduce the problem with only the spacy.load line? (If so, the rest of your code may not need to be included in the question; as per the "minimal" part of the [MRE] definition, a question should have the shortest code possible that causes the problem at hand when run without any changes; if it happened only when loading a custom config file, then, we'd want the load line and that config file).

No the problem was not recreated with just space.load line. The streamline server was successfully running but after I uploaded the pdf file to it such an error was being displayed
